# Is there a Latin expression one could use for "love nest"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

A friend asked me the other night over dinner how to say "love nest" in Latin. He was joking, but it got me thinking. Obviously one could say "domus/domuncula ubi amatur" or something like that (which is what I ended up offering him), but is there an idiomatic or literary term one could use to express this idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps *thalamus*?  It doesn't refer to a house or apartment where lovers meet (if that's what you had in mind specifically), but rather the room in which secret assignations occur.  Given that the *thalamus* is typically the bedchamber, it's no wonder.

> *“Hic fuit, hic cubuit; thalamo dormivimus illo:*
>   *Hic mihi lasciva*
>   *gaudia nocte dedit.”*
>
> “Here was she, here she lay; in that chamber did we sleep; here did
>   she give me wanton joys at night.”

Ovid, *Remedia Amoris*, 727-8